# What is the formal definition of interpretation of a formal language?

Tags: logic

Is there a formal version of "An interpretation is an assignment of meaning to the symbols of a formal language?"

I'm looking for something akin to the formal definition of "is an element of" relation, which would be "subset of U x P(U)," i.e. a subset of the cartesian product of the domain set and its power set.

I'm aware an interpretation is an activity outside the logical system, but was wondering if there is a formal definition in metalogic or something.

Comment: Yes these are called structure/model in most logics such as in the classic [FOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_structures): *The most common way of specifying an interpretation (especially in mathematics) is to specify a structure (also called a model; see below). The structure consists of a domain of discourse D and an interpretation function I mapping non-logical symbols to predicates, functions, and constants...*

Comment: Yes, it is described in every math logic textbook.

Comment: See [Interpretation (logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)) as well as [Classical Logic: Semantics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/#Sema).

Comment: And see e.g. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/841160/small-confusion-with-first-order-language-and-interpretations)

Comment: Just read any proper logic text (i.e. written by a logician) such as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684208/21820). Neither wikipedia nor SEP are suitable for learning the basics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the typical model theoretic approach is as follows. Fix a first order language L and signature S. Fix also some set A. A S-structure is a tuple (A, I), where I is the interpretation function such that, given any n-ary relation symbol R in S, assigns some subset of A^n, denoted as I(R). Since functions are (in set theory) just specialized relations, this generalizes to functions as well.